# How should I store one variable persistently?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, storage

Currently I'm developing a Firefox extension. Now I need to store the values of two variables persistently so that the values can be accessed even if Firefox is restarted.

I already found the following ways to store data:

- [SQLite Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage)
- [Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences)

But isn't it a bit complicated to create a whole database just for two values?
And maybe this sounds a bit strange but I do not really want to save the values in the Preferences because in fact they are just data and no preference.

I can't really decide which way would be best. How would you store the data? Are there perhaps other ways to store data of a Firefox extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use preferences, that's what they are good for. For small amounts of data that needs to be remembered they are the perfect solution. And you can easily access them on the `about:config` page.

As to other methods of storing data: attributes in XUL documents can be [persisted in `localstore.rdf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Persistent_Data). You can simply [save data to a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm) (probably [JSON-encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON)). Well, you could even write your data into the Windows registry (no, not going to give a link to that). But using preferences should be the better solution nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you. Then I'll simply use the preferences. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies?

[Firefox Cookie Tutorial](http://mozilla.gunnars.net/firefox_help_firefox_cookie_tutorial.html)

[Jquery- setting cookies](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

Comment: So, how would a Firefox **extension** use cookies?